# Приветствие пользователя анимированным текстом  в приложении iOS

Tags: xcode, анимация, objective-c

Хочу сделать анимированное приветствие пользователя. Смотрю в сторону метода

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3 delay:10 options: UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedCurve
animations:^{
        // code 
}
```

Проблема в том, что если делать анимированные view, например, их движение или изменение фона, то, изменяя параметры, получается. Как сделать это для label (принимая во внимание, что он наследник view), делать так же, но текст появляется сразу (не через несколько секунд). И как сделать, чтобы появлялось по букве, как бы печатает машинкой.

Подскажите, в какую сторону смотреть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно, можно сделать [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686642/letter-by-letter-animation-for-uilabel) или [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14138459/how-can-you-sequentially-show-the-characters-within-a-string-in-a-uilabel). Но я Вам этого не рекомендую.

#### YetiCharacterLabel

Рекомендую, очень хорошо смотрится. Особенно для `YETIMotionLabel`, при изменения текста с пустого на Ваш будет как раз эффект появления по букве.
Почитать о этом решении можно у них в [блоге](http://swiftyeti.com/texteffects-with-nslayoutmanager/).

https://github.com/android1989/YetiCharacterLabelExample

[image: img]

Также неплохо смотрятся на экране приветствия:

RQShineLabel - https://github.com/zipme/RQShineLabel

[image: img]

Shimmer - https://github.com/facebook/Shimmer

[image: img]